# I get an error when trying to establish a $ lookup relationship in Mongodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lookup

I'm at the learning stage yet.

I am having trouble establishing a relationship in Mongodb.

error not found 404
I made all the operations in the collections with the data in both tables, and in the training I received. But somehow I couldn't run it successfully.

Models Books

```
    const Book = require('../Models/Book');

    router.post('/new', function(req, res, next) {
        const  book = new Book({
            title: 'Hikayelerde ve çocuk',
            userId: '5ed267005e5d568b58cd17f7',
            published: true,
            category: 'Hikaye',
            comment: [
                {
                    author: "Macit",
                    mail: "macit@macit.com",
                    subject:"Kitap fena değil",
                    message: "Bu kitap oldukça güzel ben çok beğendim ",
                },
                {
                    author: "Mutlu",
                    mail: "mutlu@mutlu.com",
                    subject:"Kitap fena değil",
                    message: "Bu kitap oldukça güzel ben çok beğendim ",

                },
            ],
            meta:
                {
                    votes: 3,
                    favs: 3
                },


        });

        book.save((err, data) => {

            if (err)
                console.log(err);

            res.json(data);
        });
    });
// aggregate $lookup
router.get('aggregate-lookup', (req, res) => {
    Book.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'userId',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'user'
            }
        }
    ], (err, result) => {
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```

module.exports = router;

Books Collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed26a1ca997a08c2d6d59bf"),
    "published" : true,
    "title" : "Hikayelerde ve çocuk",
    "userId" : ObjectId("5ed267005e5d568b58cd17f7"),
    "category" : "Hikaye",
    "comment" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ed26a1ca997a08c2d6d59c0"),
            "author" : "Macit",
            "mail" : "macit@macit.com",
            "message" : "Bu kitap oldukça güzel ben çok beğendim "
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ed26a1ca997a08c2d6d59c1"),
            "author" : "Mutlu",
            "mail" : "mutlu@mutlu.com",
            "message" : "Bu kitap oldukça güzel ben çok beğendim "
        }
    ],
    "meta" : {
        "votes" : 3,
        "favs" : 3
    },
    "publishedAt" : ISODate("2020-05-30T14:13:48.440Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Book

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const BookSchema = new Schema({

    title: String,

    comment: [
        {
            author: String,
            mail: String,
            subjet: String,
            message: String,
        },
    ],
    category: String,
    meta: {
        votes: Number,
        favs: Number
    },


    published: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },

    publishedAt : {
        type: Date,
        // şuanki tarih
        default: Date.now
    },
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID
    },

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

User Collection

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ed267005e5d568b58cd17f7"),
    "published" : true,
    "name" : "Macit Mutlu Sarı",
    "age" : "34",
    "about" : "Ankara doğumlu ve güzel sanatlar mezunu 18 yıllık deneyimi olan bir profesyonel",
    "publishedAt" : ISODate("2020-05-30T14:00:32.322Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your are making the right HTTP request? MongoDB should return empty or throw error if your request is wrong. Could you share HTTP requests you've made?

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem.

 I forgot to put in / on the router.

 But I have another question.

 I can only do one operation in the User ID (userId) of the Books Model. How do I match all the data? What should come to the userId section?

Answer (score 0):

Replace _Id with _id

```
$lookup: {
               from: 'users',
               localField: '_id', //Replace here
               foreignField: 'userId',
               as: 'user'
           }
```

Comment: Thank you Vicky, new question up comments, help please